# What is a magnetic radius?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

What is a magnetic radius (e.g. of a hadron)?  And how does this differ from the charge radius?

Comment: By magnetic radius, do you mean something different from [gyroradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroradius)?

Comment: Yes.  That is why I posted here.  Google kept giving a lot of bad results, with "gyroradius" being the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proton is the most well measured hadron: they are plentiful and available in cryo-liquid form for electron scattering experiments. Moreover, the charge radius can be estimated via hyper-fine splitting measurements. The neutron is a bit more difficult, as there are no free neutron targets.

The charge radius is the RMS radius, $r$, of the charge density, $\rho(r)$, and is 0.84-0.88 fm.

The magnetic radius of the proton is the RMS radius of the magnetic moment distribution, and is very nearly 0.78 fm.

A detailed comparison of the two is a major undertaking (on the scale of SE answer) involving comparisons of statistical and systematic errors involved in various experimental techniques and theoretical models.

---

Edited by Nicole Sharp with data from https://pdg.lbl.gov/

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering if it might be related to magnetic moment.  So it is basically the average amount of space that the magnetic moment is localized to.

Comment: The Particle Data Group actually gives a smaller magnetic radius (0.78 fm) for the proton than its charge radius (0.84-0.88 fm).